# Manipulation of values fed in from an hourly API with react.js

Tags: javascript, json, api, reactjs

I'm bringing in data from an API which is updated periodically (every hour on the hour), for example:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1479835508,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDUSD":1,
    "USDJPY":110.971001,
  }
}
```

Some of the values are numeric, and these will change. So, for example one hour later I could have:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1479835509,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDUSD":1,
    "USDJPY":111.03221,
  }
}
```

I call the API from within my react.js class component as (I've omitted my private API access key for privacy reasons):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var component = this;
    var MY_ACCESS_KEY  = "<omitted private data>";
    var MY_CHOSEN_CURRENCIES = "USD,JPY,CAD,RUB,CNY,GBP,EUR,BTC,CHF"
      $.get("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=" + MY_ACCESS_KEY + "&currencies=" + MY_CHOSEN_CURRENCIES + "&format=1", function(data) {
        component.setState(data)
      });
  }
```

I was wondering, if I could somehow store the previous JSON that was pulled down from my API, such that I could then calculate the percentage change in the USDJPY value>?

N.B. I understand the mathematics of it - ((USDJPY_new/USD_old)/USDJPY_old)*100 = percentage_change - I just need to know how to store and then access the data. Just not sure of any ideas of how to log the previous values to make such a calculation!

Q. I am wondering if there is a way of storing this API data locally (only the previous JSON pulled down) and then when the data changes in the API (and not when someone reloads the website - i.e., when the timestamps change) I can then work out this percentage change.

Comment: Are you *only* making the API call on `componentDidMount`?

Comment: @arb Hi Arb, yes...is this not good practise? Would you suggest something better?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [JavaScript Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). This allows you to locally store serialized data in a key-value-store for later access.

You could for example serialize the API response using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and store it. In addition to that, store the date and time of the last request.

Now you can compare this timestamp to the current date and decide based on that whether you can reuse the data or if it is expired and you need to make an API call.

Comment: Would storing it locally work tho? I need to track the stored data, this may overwrite any stored APIs.

Comment: If you need to keep the historic data, make it an array of API responses. You can store any JS data structures that are serializable.

Comment: Hi Timo, I have tried a few things they have suggested but I can't get it to work within the React.js environment I'm afraid.

Comment: I may be able to help you. Add your attempts to the question, describe your issues and I'll have a look.

Comment: I'm just getting various syntax errors - I clearly don't know how to use the guidebook. Just moved into react.js.